# MySQL error 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Tags: php, mysql, database

i have two tables in a DB with the following structure:

table 1: 3 rows - category_id, product_id and position

table 2: 3 rows - category_id, product_id and position

i am trying to set table 1 position to table 2 position where category and product id is the same from the tables.

below is the sql i have tried to make this happen but returns MySQL error 1242 - subquery returns more then 1 row

```
UPDATE table1 
SET position = (
    SELECT position 
    FROM table2 
    WHERE table1.product_id = table2.product_id AND table1.category_id = table2.category_id
)
```

Comment: try to run your INNER query separately and tell us the results

Comment: i get the following error

 #1054 - Unknown column 'table1.product_id' in 'where clause'

Comment: then i receive  #1052 - Column 'position' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: That means MYSQL is confused with `postion` is which one and from which table ... 

You should follow some MySQL tutorials first

Comment: i tried table1.position in the inner join select you posted and i now received all position rows from table1

Comment: By the way `You can't specify target table  for update in FROM clause`

Comment: use `GROUP BY table1.product_id`

Comment: `SELECT position FROM table2 INNER JOIN table1 ON table1.product_id = table2.product_id AND table1.category_id = table2.category_id 
GROUP BY table1.product_id`

Comment: i tried 

`UPDATE table1 
SET position =(SELECT table2.position ON table2 INNER JOIN table1 WHERE table1.product_id = table2.product_id AND table1.category_id = table2.category_id GROUP BY table1.product_id)` but i received the #1064 error near `ON table2 INNER JOIN table1 WHERE `

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is very simple and it can be done in two simple steps. The first step is just a preview of what will be changed, to avoid destroying data. It can be skipped if you are confident of your `WHERE` clause.

#### Step 1: preview the changes

Join the tables using the fields you want to match, select everything for visual validation of the match.

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id
        AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id
```

You can also add a `WHERE` clause if only some of the rows must be modified.

#### Step2: do the actual update

Replace the `SELECT` clause and the `FROM` keyword with `UPDATE`, add the `SET` clause where it belongs. Keep the `WHERE` clause:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
    INNER JOIN table2 t2
        ON t1.category_id = t2.category_id
        AND t1.product_id = t2.product_id
SET t1.position = t2.position
```

**That's all.**

#### Technical considerations

Indexes on the columns used on the `JOIN` clause on both tables are a must when the tables have more than several hundred rows. If the query doesn't have `WHERE` conditions then MySQL will use indexes only for the biggest table. Indexes on the fields used on the `WHERE` condition will speed up the query. Prepend `EXPLAIN` to the `SELECT` query to check the execution plan and decide what indexes do you need.

You can add `SORT BY` and `LIMIT` to further reduce the set of changed rows using criteria that cannot be achieved using `WHERE` (for example, only the most recent/oldest 100 rows etc). Put them on the `SELECT` query first to validate the outcome then morph the `SELECT` into an `UPDATE` as described.
Of course, indexes on the columns used on the `SORT BY` clause are a must.

Answer (score 0):

You can run this query to see what is happening:

```
SELECT product_id, category_id, count(*), min(position), max(position)
FROM table2
GROUP BY product_id, category_id
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1;
```

This will give you the list of `product_id`, `category_id` pairs that appear multiple times in `table2`.  Then you can decide what to do.  Do you want an arbitrary value of `position`?  Is the value of `position` always the same?  Do you need to fix the table?

It is easy enough to fix the particular problem by using `limit 1` or an aggregation function.  However, you may really need to fix the data in the table.  A fix looks like:

```
UPDATE table1 t1
    SET t1.position = (SELECT t2.position 
                       FROM table2  t2
                       WHERE t2.product_id = t1.product_id AND t2.category_id = t1.category_id
                       LIMIT 1
                      );
```

Comment: it is a db created by someone else so there is no column with a unique identify e.g. ID, there is just 3 rows and what i need to happen is if table2.category_id = table1.category_id and table2.product_id = table1.product_id then set table1.position to the value of table2.position which has the category and product id

Comment: @RyanK . . . Then use `limit 1`, or `select max(t2.position)`.  Either of these will fix the problem.